# ActivityViewModel + AdapterItemViewModel connection

Tags: android, architecture, viewmodel, android-recyclerview

guys!
I have the problem with creating architecture for my app. Can you please help me?
I have an activity with recyclerView containing radiobuttons and "save" button. I need to get selected item from recyclerView to sharedPreferences. But how can I get the selected item from adapterItemViewModel and save it inside the activityViewModel into shareds? I don't have an access so maybe some callback or observable will be fine in this case?

Comment: Could you attach code of your adapter (and its adapterItemViewModel?), please?

Comment: If you have regular adapter with items: List<Data> just add method getSelected(): Int to it, and return items.find { it.selected == true }